# Why does the python code result in the user being incorrect in all circumstances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, conditional-statements, computer-science

The following code is supposed to prompt the user to guess the winning pick. The code tells me what the correct answer is so i can test it, however the program will sometimes tell me i've won with the correct answer, but fails to tell me i've won a majority of the time, without me changing any code. Is there something wrong with my conditionals? Is there a more consolidated manner i should be doing this?

```
import random

def generateWinningPick():

    aRandomInteger = random.randrange(1,4)
    #calls up a random number from the range 1-6 and assigns it the animals to a random number 1-3
    anotherRandomNum = random.randrange(1,6)
    if (anotherRandomNum == 1):
        return "monkey" + str(aRandomInteger)
        
    elif (anotherRandomNum == 2):
        return "dragon" + str(aRandomInteger)
        
    elif (anotherRandomNum == 3):
        return "snake" + str(aRandomInteger)
        
    #same as 6 lines written above however this accounts for the user putting the number before the animal
    elif (anotherRandomNum == 4):
        return str(aRandomInteger) + "dragon"
        
    elif (anotherRandomNum == 5):
        return str(aRandomInteger) + "monkey"
       
    else:
        return str(aRandomInteger) + "snake"
    
    
    

def main ():
    #prompt user to input their guess
    winningConcatenation=[str(generateWinningPick())]
    print(generateWinningPick())
    print("lottery pic checker v1.2. lets see if you've won a prize. The word choices are monkey, dragon and snake and the digits are 1,2 and 3")
    print("The winning pick is a word and a digit, in some order")
    userGuess=input(str("What is your word/number combination?"))
    #while userGuess is not valid explain why and prompt again
    numsPoss=['1','2','3']
    
    
    #declare variables numEntered and wordEntered using [] to empty string
    numEntered=[]
    wordEntered=[]
    #if first character is 1,2 or 3 set the values for both lists by appending the list
    if (userGuess[0]) in numsPoss:
        numEntered.append(str(userGuess[0]))
        wordEntered.append(str(userGuess[0:]))
            
        if ((numEntered[0] and wordEntered[0]) in (winningConcatenation)):
            print ("congratulations, you win!")
    #elif check if users word is winnning word but not number
        elif ((wordEntered[0]) in (winningConcatenation) and (numEntered[0]) not in (winningConcatenation)):
            print ("your guessed word",wordEntered, "was correct but the winning number is not", numEntered)
    #elif check if users number is winning number but not word
        elif ((numEntered[0]) in (winningConcatenation) and (wordEntered[0]) not in (winningConcatenation)):
            print ("your guessed number",numEntered, "was correct but not the word", wordEntered)
    #else print you guessed neither word nor number
        else:
            print("you guessed neither the word or number")
        
    #if last character is the string 1,2 or 3 set values for both lists by apending the list
    elif (userGuess[-1]) in numsPoss:
        numEntered.append(str(userGuess[-1]))
        wordEntered.append(str(userGuess[:(len(userGuess))-1]))
        
    #check if users word and number are winning pick
        if ((wordEntered[0] and numEntered[0]) in (winningConcatenation)):
            print ("congratulations, you win!")
    #elif check if users word is winnning word but not number
        elif ((wordEntered[0]) in (winningConcatenation) and (numEntered[0]) not in (winningConcatenation)):
            print ("your guessed word",wordEntered, "was correct but the winning number is not", numEntered)
    #elif check if users number is winning number but not word
        elif ((numEntered[0]) in (winningConcatenation) and (wordEntered[0]) not in (winningConcatenation)):
            print ("your guessed number",numEntered, "was correct but not the word", wordEntered)
    #else print you guessed neither word nor number
        else:
            print("you guessed neither the word or number")
     
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in here:

```
def main ():
    #prompt user to input their guess
    winningConcatenation=[str(generateWinningPick())]
    print(generateWinningPick())
```

You think you are printing the answer, but you are generating a new random combination and printing it. Instead of this `print(generateWinningPick())`, do this:

```
print(winningConcatenation)
```